# Passing a Python list to function, to insert into json list

Tags: python

I am passing URLs to a filtering service.  The json body I post is:

```
body = {
    "url-filter": [
        "www.reddit.com",
        "www.cnn.com",
        "www.espn.com"
    ]
}
```

I would like to create a function that will allow me to pass one or more URLs to filter.  What is unclear to me is:

1) How I should pass these URLs to a function - Python list?  The URLs do not need to retain order/sequence.

2) How I should insert the URLs into this json body?

Is there a function that will do this or is something more required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do this:

```
body['url-filter'].append("www.myaddress.com")
```

If you want to add multiple URLs, do this to add a list of URLs:

```
body['url-filter'] += list_of_urls
```

Answer (score 1):

You're asking two questions here, the first one is how you pass the URLs to a function, the second is how you add another URL to the list.

The code that you show is valid python code for a dictionary with one single key `url-filter`. So you can pass the list of URLs to a python function like this:

```
myfunction(body['url-filter'])
```

If you actually meant that `body` is a json encoded string, you can decode that string using `json.loads` like this

```
import json
decoded_body = json.loads(body)
```

and then you can pass it to a function.
If you want to add another URL to the list of URLs, you can simply append that URL by `body['url-filter'].append('www.new-url.com'). This becomes a little more involved if body was actually meant to be a string. You would first want to decode the string into a python object, then append the new url and finally encode everything as json again.

```
def add_url(body, url):
    json_body = json.loads(body)
    json_body['url-filter'].append(url)
    return json.dumps(json_body)
```

Comment: When I do this, I get backslashes in the json msg.  Example:

Comment: Where do you get backslashes when you do what?